# array of objects map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, I'm pulling an API, which is filled with an array of objects.
When trying to map it I get following error: "Uncaught TypeError: benchmarkData.map is not a function"

While I get the error, it actually does the job (when I log it I get the asked result), it just prevents loading the other elements.

This is how my API looks:

```
[
{
"type": "drgmbmk",
"test": "5782",
"DEAANTA": "412",
"DEGEMAT": "235",
"DEGEMGW": "97.7",
"DEGEMMB": "3.39",
"DEGEMNV": "64.1",
"DEGEMSD": "13.2",
"DEGEMVD": "71.3",
"DEJAART": "2022",
"DELTMCE": "-",
"DEWEENR": "1"
},
{
"type": "drgmbmk",
"test": "5782",
"DEAANTA": "436",
"DEGEMAT": "233",
"DEGEMGW": "120.1",
"DEGEMMB": "3.38",
"DEGEMNV": "64.2",
"DEGEMSD": "13.2",
"DEGEMVD": "71.4",
"DEJAART": "2022",
"DELTMCE": "ALL",
"DEWEENR": "1"
},
{
"type": "drgmbmk",
"test": "5782",
"DEAANTA": "22",
"DEGEMAT": "213",
"DEGEMGW": "99.9",
"DEGEMMB": "3.23",
"DEGEMNV": "64.9",
"DEGEMSD": "12.7",
"DEGEMVD": "72.8",
"DEJAART": "2022",
"DELTMCE": "BBC",
"DEWEENR": "1"
}
]
```

This is my React code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (benchmarkData) {
      setSupplierHasData(true);
      let loadingplaceFilter = [];
      const loadingPlaces = [];
      benchmarkData.map(item => { //!start of requested question code
        if(item.type === "drlvbmk") {
           loadingPlaces.push(item.DELPLCE, item.DELTMCE, item.DEELTCE)
        }
      }
      ); //!end of requested question code
      console.log(loadingPlaces);

      const uniqueLoadingplaces = [];
      loadingPlaces.map((item) => {
        var findItem = uniqueLoadingplaces.find((x) => x === item);
        if (!findItem) uniqueLoadingplaces.push(item);
      });
      console.log('uniqueloadingplaces', uniqueLoadingplaces);


      setFilters({
        ...filters,
        loadingplaces: loadingplaceFilter,
      });

      setFilterData(true);

  }, [benchmarkData]);
```

Pulling the api:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBenchmarkData = async () => {
      setFetchNewData(false);
      console.log('current user active id :', suppliersState.suppliers.activeID, "current user active uuid:  ", suppliersState.suppliers.activeUUID);
      try  {
        await axios
      
          .get(
            `https://bpg-ap.ddev.site/jsonapi/benchmarking_get_data?supplierid=${suppliersState.suppliers.activeID}&date_from=1&date_to=2022`
          )
          .then(res => {
            setBenchmarkData(res.data);
            console.log('BENCHMARKINGRESULTAAT : ', res.data);
          });
        } catch(error) {
          setSupplierHasData(false);
          setChartData({});
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    if (benchmarkData === null) {
      console.log('useEffect fired, fetch benchmarkData', benchmarkData);
      fetchBenchmarkData();
    } 
  }, [benchmarkData, suppliersState.suppliers.activeID]);
```

Logging benchmarkData results in:
[image]

I hope anyone can help me to solve this problem

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint on that line and seeing what `benchmarkData` is? The error would seem to indicate that you don't have the data you think you do.

Comment: Check if `benchmarkData` have some data or not. Try to see in console.

Comment: Thank you sirs for your answer, the benchmarkdata has data @Ankit  & crashmstr

Comment: i don't know much about useEffect for now but as far as i can see
benchmarkData already is an array so why in the last line of code you are putting it inside another array 
[benchmarkData]

Comment: Can you make a code sandbox?

Comment: @Ahmadghoneim no idea mate, this code was not written by me, I'm adding some new functionalities

Comment: Don't worry for the [benchmarkData]. It is the dependencies for the useEffect. Are you sure benchmarkData is not a string ? As it comes from an API, maybe it can be the problem. What do you have if you console.log(benchmarkData) ?

Comment: @OneQ Hey, I added a screenshot of the logged data.

Comment: since you are putting a dependency on useEffect, this mean if the state of benchemarkData change, for ex "null" it will triger all the process in the useffect, and map will not be able to run on data ''nul'' : that why is not a function. So depending what you want, if you only want to run once, remove it, don't use the conditional statement "if"

Comment: @ShueiYang If I leave that out, I get the same error.

Comment: @arnemichiels the console.log(benchmarkData) you log is under the useEffect ?

Comment: @ShueiYang It was inside the useEffect

Comment: well I simulate your code (leaving out the filter) with your data example it work, maybe you need to show more where the data come from, as for now i can't really tell.

Comment: @ShueiYang Hey, I added how I pull the api.

Comment: what is the state of benchemarkData when you set up the useState ?  if is empty or null than remove completly the useEffect on the map function and use only if statement.

Comment: @ShueiYang it is null in useState

Comment: @ShueiYang Hey, I put the map outside the useEffect which gave the same error.